# Earlier updated values disappears in gridview while updating

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have `gridview`, in which I update a row of it. Till this it works fine, but

> when I go to edit the second row. what happens here is. The earlier updated value disappears and second value gets updated.

Below is my code of UPDATING

```
protected void GrdCategoryDetails_UpdateCommand(object sender, GridRecordEventArgs e)
{
    string Amount = string.Empty;
    Amount = e.Record["AMOUNT"].ToString();
    Session["V_ID"] = e.Record["VENDOR_ID"];
    Session["Amount"] = Amount;
}
public void RowDataBound(object sender, Obout.Grid.GridRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == GridRowType.DataRow)
    {
        string Vendor_ID = Convert.ToString(Session["V_ID"]);
        if(e.Row.Cells[1].Text == Vendor_ID)
        {
            string Amount = Convert.ToString(Session["Amount"]);
            e.Row.Cells[5].Text = Amount;
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea what's wrong here

Comment: @MsYvette: I m saving that data into the session. Here `Session["Amount"] = Amount;`

Comment: @MsYvette: So how to change that in `Session` ?? as per my code

Comment: See, on pageload my grid is already binded. In that grid there is a feature to edit the `Amount` column. So with my current code what happening here is **it is saving data with updated value for the first time, but when I go to edit the next row the earlier saved data gets disappears.** There is no other code for updated values. its just user edits and inputs the updated value from the gridview.

Comment: I am populating the grid data from `SqlDataSource` yes i guess the session data is not being changed.

Comment: @MsYvette: are you their ? any suggestion on what to do ahead for this

Comment: sure waiting for your reply. by the time, I have my lunch :)

Comment: @MsYvette: are you online on chat now ?